# After upgrade php version 7.4 to 8.1 soapCall not working

Tags: php, php-7.4, php-8.1

After upgrade php version 7.4 to 8.1 soapCall not working.
I have debugged both ini file and both look like same

PHP 7.4 : /usr/local/php7.4/etc/cli/php.ini
[image]

PHP 8.1 :  /usr/local/php8.1/etc/cli/php.ini

[image]

PHP 7.4 soap call is working fine , but 8.1 soap call fail and getting error "Could not connect to host". But same code working fine at 7.4.
Why soap call not working at 8.1, anyone can help me ?

Comment: Please don't post text as an image. Also please include the code responsible for connecting to the webservice

Comment: We are calling normal __soapCall() ,

Answer (score 0):

If you recently upgraded from PHP version 7.4 to 8.1 and are now experiencing issues with the soapCall function, it could be due to changes in the PHP 8.1 release.

One potential issue is that PHP 8.1 no longer supports the SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS option, which was used to control how SOAP responses were parsed. If your code is using this option, you may need to update it to use the new SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE option instead.

Another potential issue is that PHP 8.1 has changed the way that SOAP headers are handled. If your code is relying on SOAP headers to pass additional information, you may need to update it to use the new SoapHeader class instead.

It's also possible that there are other changes in PHP 8.1 that are causing issues with your soapCall function. To diagnose the issue, you may want to review the PHP upgrade guide and changelog, as well as check your error logs for any relevant error messages. You may also want to consult the documentation for the SOAP library that you're using to see if there are any specific compatibility issues with PHP 8.1.